# I am trying to convert HTML to pdf using node-html-pdf npm package. The problem is that the pdf is not interpreting the mathematics symbols

Tags: node.js, npm, html-to-pdf

```
    var fs = require("fs");
var pdf = require("html-pdf");
var html = fs.readFileSync("./new.html", "ascii", (err, data) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(data);
});
var options = { format: "Letter" };

pdf.create(html, options).toStream(function (err, stream) {
  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./foo(2).pdf"));
});
```

[This image is the screenshot of the HTML file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFjef.png)

[This image is the screenshot of the output PDF file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSk5j.png)
Here the square root symbol is present but the +- signs are gone and also the alignment is gone. Is there a way to convert HTML as it is to printable pdf?

Comment: could you add your html file?

Comment: For alignment, I think you can try setting viewport size